# Heroku Error: No application module specified. Django

Tags: django, heroku

When I deploy my Django app on Heroku I got following error

```
 Error: No application module specified.
```

I cleary see that Heroku see wsgi file

```
Starting process with command `gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug`
```

But then I got this error. My Procfile looks like this

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

The WSGI

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'george_paintings.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I tried to see logs with

```
heroku run rails console -a george-paintings
```

but got an error

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You simply paste cmd
```

your terminal ( heroku logs --tail ) its shows your error

Comment: heroku logs --tail -a george-paintings
 shows only Process exited with status 1 error